# Por que me da error ErrorException Undefined offset: 0 (View: App\resources\views\index.blade.php) con cualquier proyecto?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

estoy trabajando con laravel v. 7 y tuve inconveniente en intentar guardar una imagen con Storage:: el detalle es que despues de que me dio el error ya no se solucionó nada ni borrando los cambios que había hecho, ni limpiando la caché del sistema ni del explorador.

Esto solo me pasa en una computadora que fue en la que hice el cambio en su momento, tengo el mismo proyecto desde otra compu (proyecto compartido en dropbox) osea que es el mismo y en la otra computadora no me da ese error. Que será?

```
ErrorException Undefined offset: 0 (View: App\resources\views\index.blade.php)
```

Pd. estoy usando laravel 7, livewire.

Este es el codigo de mi componente:
public $cantidad, $fecha, $referencia, $imagen, $nom_imagen, $per;

```
$aporte = Aporte::create([
        $this->nom_imagen = date('YmdHis').'.jpg',
        $this->imagen->storeAs('imagenes',$this->nom_imagen,'publico'),
        'id_concepto_pago' => $this->id_concepto_pago,
        'cantidad' => $this->cantidad,
        'fecha' => $this->fecha,
        'referencia' => $this->referencia,
        'id_personal' => $this->id_personal,
        'imagen' => $this->nom_imagen
      ]);
```

aunque con el codigo aun tengo inconveniente porque me da el error de:

```
$this->imagen->storeAs('imagenes',$this->nom_imagen,'publico'),
```

que aun no he logrado resolver ya que la imagen no va nula, si le coloco una pero es como que si no la cargara cuando le doy click en guardar.

Comment: El error es claro, probablemente debas tener una variable declarada en tu componente la cual no tiene ningún valor, y me imagino que en tu vista debes tener algo como `variable[0]`, y dado que no hay data asignada a esa variable, te da el error.

Comment: pero borré cache de todo, de laravel y del navegador, hasta reinicié el equipo, curiosamente como menciono en otra computadora si funciona (es el mismo proyecto)

Comment: Si te sale el error en esa vista, prueba borrarla y crear otra

Comment: Al parecer el error se relaciona archivos, pon el código de tu componente donde manejas los archivos y el nombre del input que tienes en tu vista

Comment: Ya agregué el código.

Comment: Lo más probable es que primero tengas que hacer una validación de si la imagen está llegando o no, algo como `if(!is_null($this->imagen)) guarda-la-imagen`

Comment: he pensado en eso, pero como la imagen no es obligatoria, no quisiera que cuando yo coloque una imagen, pero el sistema no me la reconozca guarde el registro y yo habiendo seleccionado la imagen, no se si me explico.